# Sending a trap with Perl's Net::SNMP

Tags: perl, snmp, cpan, net-snmp

I'm trying to send a trap as part of a larger Perl script.  I've copied the trapsending code to another file, and am running it by itself.  The code seems to think the trap sends successfully, yet I'm not seeing the trap on either machine that I have a trap listener running on.

Here's the code:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SNMP;

#messy hardcoding
my $snmp_target = '192.168.129.50';
#my $snmp_target = '10.200.6.105'; # Server running trap listener
my $enterprise = '1.3.6.1.4.1.27002.1';

my ($sess, $err) = Net::SNMP->session(
    -hostname  => $snmp_target,
    -version => 1, #trap() requires v1
);

if (!defined $sess) {
    print "Error connecting to target ". $snmp_target . ": ". $err;
    next;
}

my @vars = qw();
my $varcounter = 1;

push (@vars, $enterprise . '.' . $varcounter);
push (@vars, OCTET_STRING);
push (@vars, "Test string");

my $result = $sess->trap(
    -varbindlist => \@vars,
    -enterprise => $enterprise,
    -specifictrap => 1,
);

if (! $result)
{
    print "An error occurred sending the trap: " . $sess->error();
}
```

EDIT: Added $sess->debug(255) call, here's the output:

```
debug: [440] Net::SNMP::Dispatcher::_event_insert(): created new head and tail [ARRAY(0x1af1fea8)]
debug: [687] Net::SNMP::Message::send(): transport address 192.168.129.50:161
debug: [2058] Net::SNMP::Message::_buffer_dump(): 70 bytes
[0000]  30 44 02 01  00 04 06 70  75 62 6C 69  63 A4 37 06   0D.....public.7.
[0016]  09 2B 06 01  04 01 81 D2  7A 01 40 04  C0 A8 81 85   .+......z.@.....
[0032]  02 01 06 02  01 01 43 01  00 30 1B 30  19 06 0A 2B   ......C..0.0...+
[0048]  06 01 04 01  81 D2 7A 01  01 04 0B 54  65 73 74 20   ......z....Test 
[0064]  73 74 72 69  6E 67                                   string
debug: [517] Net::SNMP::Dispatcher::_event_delete(): deleted [ARRAY(0x1af1fea8)], list is now empty
```

EDIT: Can anyone running a trap listener try this code on their machine and let me know if it works?

EDIT: Tried it from my MBP.  Same result.  Then noticed that the debug info says it is sending to port 161.  Forced `-port => 162` parameter, and it works.  That leaves me with a couple of questions:

1. Why does the trap sender default to 161?
2. I get this error when I run with debug on.  What does it mean?

   error: [97] Net::SNMP::Transport::IPv4::UDP::agent_addr(): Failed to disconnect: Address family not supported by protocol family

Comment: Can you sniff network traffic to check what it is really sent? Maybe problem is on other side or routing sends it somewhere unexpected? You can also try to enable debug mode with `$sess->debug(255)` on session.

Comment: From the debug, it looks like its sending.  I'll add the output above.

Comment: Does sending a trap with `snmptrap` works? I think many server don't accept v1 trap.

Comment: Confirmed, sending a v1 trap with `snmptrap` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing 'Port' setting from default 161 to 162.

Comment: I was trying your script as it is but i got the following error can please help me to understand the error?
`Can't locate Net/SNMP.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::SNMP module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1/arm-linux /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.30.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30.1/arm-linux /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.30.1 /usr/lib/perl5/5.30.1/arm-linux /usr/lib/perl5/5.30.1 .) at testing_perl.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at testing_perl.pl line 5.`